# Difference between ながら, がてら and つつ

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between ながら, がてら and つつ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ながら means doing multiple things simultaneously.

がてら means to do one thing at somewhere middle along way to doing another.

つつ means doing multiple things alongside but not necessarily simultaneously, little by little in turn.

> 運転しながら食事する
>   'eat while driving'
>
> 運転(し)がてら食事する
>   'eating along the way driving (after having driven half way)'
>
> 運転しつつ食事する
>   'take a bite and drive a little, take a bite and drive a little, ...'

Comment: Yep, same here, I don't quite get your explanation of がてら. Could you please add a few more examples of it in use?

Comment: がてらに = […をかねて。…のついでに。](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%82%89)  So it sounds to me like XがてらにY is like, X is the main thing, and Y is incidental, happening along the way (maybe just because it can, or it's convenient...or whatever).

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that when using ながら, the second half of the sentence is the main/important task. So your first sentence probably gives the impression that you prioritize eating over driving, and would translate to 'driving while eating'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the meaning is to drive half the journey (for example) stop for food and then drive again to.the destination.

"We stopped for food on the way here"

Comment: Hello there, Stu, and welcome to JLU! I think you were trying to make a comment on Sawa's answer, but what you did is make your own answer. Unfortunately commenting requires at least 50 reputation. To find out more about reputation and privileges, please read the FAQ. I look forward to having you in the community! http://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation